# QGIS Lost precision when converting raster to vector

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, convert

I am after running ordinary kriging, converting raster to vector I lose decimal value and only get whole number.  I have added first the raster then the vector image.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of precision are you expecting? You will end up with tiny vector cells with any significant precision.